# Adding re.compile to list

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

When I compile a regex and assign it to a variable or add it to a list, I suspiciously get different behaviour on Python 2.x and 3.x.

```
import re
z = re.compile('a')
print(z)
```

Above snippet prints on 2.x

```
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7ff839e57030>
```

and on 3.x

```
re.compile('a')
```

The first one looks like the regex is compiled and ready to go whenever I need it (which is what I want) but the second one still says `re.compile`.

Does that mean the regex is compiled on the fly when I need it and even worse recompiled every time I reference `z` and do something like `z.match('a')`? Or is the described Python 3 behaviour just cosmetic and it also maintains a compiled copy under the hood?

My point is, I (statically) compile my regexes at the beginning of the source file, so can save some time where I repetitively reference them in loops but if this is not happening, then that isn't good.

Comment: you are not clear, there is no difference

Comment: @Hackaholic, I think you are right, because even on P3, both print(z.__class__) and print(z.pattern) show what is expected. So, the object is already created. However, I'm not still sure if I really like the P3 way of stringifying the SRE_Pattern object. What if we have a string var which holds 're.compile(\'a\')'? They'd print exactly the same. Maybe it's because I'm used to P2 way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All this means is that the `__repr__` of `_sre.SRE_Pattern` has been changed, from the (not terribly helpful) default `"<classname object at address>"` to something more useful. Per [the data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) (emphasis mine):

> If at all possible, [the `__repr__` string representation of an object] **should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object** with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form `<...some useful description...>` should be returned.

Compare 2.x:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = re.compile('a')
>>> a
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x02654440>
>>> type(a)
<type '_sre.SRE_Pattern'>
>>> repr(a)
'<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x02654440>'
```

And 3.x:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = re.compile('a')
>>> a
re.compile('a')
>>> type(a)
<class '_sre.SRE_Pattern'>
>>> repr(a)
"re.compile('a')"
```

There is no difference in behaviour - the regular expression is still only compiled once (that's the whole point).

Comment: Right, this all makes perfect sense and aligns better with other languages (i.e. Java string method etc) I suppose. Thanks very much.